# Walking over Ruah Ra'a: why not?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, ruach-rah

Some Posekim write (Yalkut Yosef Hilchot Mayim Aharonim and Mishna Berura 181, 4 and IIRC the Magen Avraham) that Mayim Aharonim has Ruah Ra'a and that once someone used the water for Mayim Aharonim we shouldn't walk over it. Why aren't we allowed to walk over Ruah Ra'a?

Comment: what do you mean- why is there a ruach raa or why can't you walk over the ruach raa

Comment: Where in those books is it written? Yakut Yosef is a voluminous work.

Comment: @DoubleAA it is brought in mishna berura 181 s"k 4

Comment: Your question is not so clear,are you asking why we can't walk over it or why is ruach ra'ah a danger? If it is the latter then the question should mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mishan Brurah in Hilchos Netilas Yadyim 4:20,21 writes that they can be harmed from the ruach raah therefore they should pour water into soft earth or a slope.Even on twigs one shouldn't pour(18).

Comment: See Biur Halacha 181:elah bkli

Comment: Your answer is correct I'm just looking for why it is dangerous.

Comment: The answer is because ruach Ra'ah is a spiritual danger,see Chullin 105b .if your question is ruach ra'ah dangerous and what is it exactly,that is a different question which you should edit.